# How to access the price range values that are set in the IPriceScaleAPI object of a chart made using `lightweight-charts` library?

Tags: reactjs, lightweight-charts

I would like to create a vertical range slider existing beside a chart made using lightweight-charts library. I would like to access the maximum and minimum values that are set in the scale before or after it is adjusted and would like to prescribe those values as the maximum and minimum of the vertical range slider. I searched throughout the documentation but could only find how to modify the autoScale options, not retrieve the set values.

I cannot find the methods to retrieve the values that I require. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which information you are looking:

1. Since you are supplying the data to the chart and you can can access the visibleRange, it is possible to determine the min and max values for the data between those dates.
2. Using the [autoScaleInfoProvider](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/SeriesOptionsCommon#autoscaleinfoprovider) that is part of the series options is way to determine what the min and max values are for the price scale. You can call the evoke the default infoProvider (which is the first parameter) and get the min and max values from there. (See the last example on the linked page).
3. If the scale has been adjusted then you can use [coordinateToPrice](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ISeriesApi#coordinatetoprice) method of the Series to get the price at certain coordinates. In this case you will want to use `0` and the height of the price scale as the two points to check. You can determine the height of the price scale by using the [timeScale height](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api/interfaces/ITimeScaleApi#height) and the chart height. You can also get this height by directly measuring the canvas element for the timescale using native browser methods.

You probably would want to use option 3.